# Calculating average of based on condition

Tags: r, dataframe

Below is my data frame,

```
    Row_ID  A      B  
       1   0       0  
       2   0       0  
       3   0       0  
       4   0       1  
       5   0       1  
       6   0       1  
       7  62.75    0  
       8  100      0  
       9  100      0 
      10  100     -1 
      11  100     -1  
      12  100     -1  
      13  100     -1   
      14  87.625  -1  
      15   0       0  
      16   0       0  
      17   0       1   
      18   0       1  
      19   10      1    
      20   13.43   1
      21   67.31   0  
      22   86.5    0
      23   99      0  
      24   99      0  
      25   99      0
```

I need to calculate average of `A` every 5 consecutive rows with the below conditions.
 And the values `1 and -1` in `B` are the two transition states.

**a** The average of `A` is based on the values in `B`.

**b** The data points from `A`to be considered for the average calculation starts from the last data point where the transition in `B` ends. (Example: Transition in `B` ends at `Row_ID = 6`, Hence row number 7,8,9,10 and 11 of `A` has to be considered for calculating average).

**c** Referring to the above example, Though there are change in values at row number 10 and 11 of `B`, corresponding rows in `A`it should be considered for calculation of average because those values were considered in average calculation in the previous iteration.

Is there any workaround code without using **`embed()`** function because my data has around 900K values and since **`embed()`** creates matrix, memory usage wont be that optimal.

**Expected Output**

```
    Row_ID  A      B   Avg  
       1   0       0     0  
       2   0       0     0  
       3   0       0     0  
       4   0       1     0  
       5   0       1     0  
       6   0       1     0  
       7  62.75    0     92.55  
       8  100      0     92.55  
       9  100      0     92.55 
      10  100     -1     92.55 
      11  100     -1     92.55  
      12  100     -1     0  
      13  100     -1     0   
      14  87.625  -1     0  
      15   0       0     2  
      16   0       0     2  
      17   0       1     2   
      18   0       1     2  
      19   10      1     2    
      20   13.43   1     0
      21   67.31   0     90.16  
      22   86.5    0     90.16
      23   99      0     90.16  
      24   99      0     90.16  
      25   99      0     90.16
```

Comment: Why is the average of rows 1-4 equal to 0 instead of 4.75?

Comment: @thelatemail I assume that is is based on the 5 consecutive elements as the first case, it is only 4 elements, then 5, then again 4,..

Comment: @thelatemail as mentioned in the question the data points to be considered for the average calculation should start where the transition value in `B` ends, value `0`  in `B` is not considered as a state, Hence in `B` transition ends at `Row_ID 4` so avg calculation starts from `5` to next 5 consecutive rows.

Comment: Updated the post based on the new example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Avg := mean(A)*(.N>4), cumsum(c(TRUE,  diff(abs(B)!=1)==1))]
df1
#    Row_ID  A  B  Avg
# 1:      1  0  0  0.0
# 2:      2  5  1  0.0
# 3:      3  6  1  0.0
# 4:      4  8  1  0.0
# 5:      5  9  0 10.2
# 6:      6  8  0 10.2
# 7:      7 15 -1 10.2
# 8:      8 17 -1 10.2
# 9:      9  2 -1 10.2
#10:     10  6  0  0.0
#11:     11  9  0  0.0
#12:     12  8 -1  0.0
#13:     13  5 -1  0.0
#14:     14  2  0  6.4
#15:     15  9  0  6.4
#16:     16  2  1  6.4
#17:     17  9  1  6.4
#18:     18 10  1  6.4
```

Or an approach by @thelatemail

```
setDT(df1)[,  Avg := mean(A) *(.N > 4) , (rleid(B) + 1) %/% 2]
```

#### Update

Based on the new example, perhaps this helps

```
setDT(df2)[, Avg := c(rep(mean(head(A, 5)), 5), rep(0, .N-5)), 
        cumsum(c(TRUE,  diff(abs(B)!=1)==1))]
df2
#    Row_ID       A  B    Avg
# 1:      1   0.000  0  0.000
# 2:      2   0.000  0  0.000
# 3:      3   0.000  0  0.000
# 4:      4   0.000  1  0.000
# 5:      5   0.000  1  0.000
# 6:      6   0.000  1  0.000
# 7:      7  62.750  0 92.550
# 8:      8 100.000  0 92.550
# 9:      9 100.000  0 92.550
#10:     10 100.000 -1 92.550
#11:     11 100.000 -1 92.550
#12:     12 100.000 -1  0.000
#13:     13 100.000 -1  0.000
#14:     14  87.625 -1  0.000
#15:     15   0.000  0  2.000
#16:     16   0.000  0  2.000
#17:     17   0.000  1  2.000
#18:     18   0.000  1  2.000
#19:     19  10.000  1  2.000
#20:     20  13.430  1  0.000
#21:     21  67.310  0 90.162
#22:     22  86.500  0 90.162
#23:     23  99.000  0 90.162
#24:     24  99.000  0 90.162
#25:     25  99.000  0 90.162
```

Comment: A variation on a theme - `dat[, avg := if(.N>=5) mean(A), by=(rleid(B)+1) %/% 2]`

Comment: @akrun and @thelatemail, Thanks for the solution.. Its working perfectly fine for the data frame that I have given in the question. But its not the case with my actual dataset. The  5 consecutive rows for the calculation of the average is not being considered. I mean its calculating average for all the values until next transition change. Scaling it down to above data frame ,its printing `6` in `Average Column` from `Row_ID 6 ~ 1` .

Comment: @ANmike I think then your example is not a good reproducible one that mimics the original dataset

Comment: @akrun Yup, you are right, I ll just update my question with my original dataset.

Comment: @akrun I my very sorry the inconvenience  caused, Please take a look at my update data frame and Kindly help.

Comment: @akrun Thanks a Lot, Working exactly as required.

Comment: @akrun Could you please clarify me on this.. Assuming that my first 5 values of the `column A` is not `0`. Then Average is being calculated though there is neither `1` or `-1` in `column B` for first 5 rows. How to avoid this?

Comment: @akrun I am finding a new error which says `Error in rep(0, .N - 5) : invalid 'times' argument` , what could be the reason? Or Could you please suggest any other work arounds?

Comment: @ANmike  It was based on the assumption that you have at least 5 or more rows.  If it is not the case, then you may have to add an `if/else` condition

Comment: @akrun Oh!!  currently my data set has around 65536 row, but still the error retains.

Comment: @ANmike  So it could be a case where the length is not a multiple of that.  Could you have new question with a small reproducible example that shows the error

Comment: @sure I ll do it.

Comment: @akrun I have Posted another question which reproduces the error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635464/calculating-average-based-on-condition-in-r. Kindly Help.