# Calculating average Based on Condition in R

Tags: r, data.table

Referring to the question ["Calculating average of based on condition"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45206230/calculating-average-of-based-on-condition/45206365?noredirect=1#comment78219079_45206365), I need to calculate `average` of the column `E` based on the column `F`

Below is my part of data frame `df` but my actual data is 65K values.

```
        E            F        
     3.130658445    -1
     4.175605237    -1
     4.949554963    0
     4.653496112    0
     4.382672845    0
     3.870951272    0
     3.905365677    0
     3.795199341    0
     3.374740696    0
     3.104690415    0
     2.801178871    0
     2.487881321    0
     2.449349554    0
     2.405409636    0
     2.090901539    0
     1.632416356    0
     1.700583696    0
     1.846504012    0
     1.949797831    0
     1.963114449    0
     2.033100326    0
     2.014312751    0
     1.997178247    0
     2.143775497    0
```

Based on the solution provided in the mentioned post, below is my script.

```
setDT(df)[, Avg := c(rep(mean(head(d$fE, 5)), 5), rep(0, .N-5)), 
      cumsum(c(TRUE,  diff(abs(F)!=1)==1))]
```

But when executed I am getting the below error.

> Error in rep(0, .N - 5) : invalid 'times' argument

Comment: That Error comes from trying to rep a value -n times. Try `rep(0, -1)`

Comment: @Sotos I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I know, you should be. I am not offering a solution, I am just explainning the error :)

Comment: Instead of telling answerers that their code doesn't meet vague conditions, explicitly show desired output for the given example. For more guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250 Btw, your q should be self-contained instead of requiring people to read linked material.

Answer (score 1):

use aggregate:

```
agg <- aggregate(df$E,by=list(df$F), FUN=mean)
```

you used a data table example, but you said data frame in your qu
data table:

```
# this will retain all rows and return mean as a new column (per group_
df[, Mean:=mean(E), by=list(F)]
# this will return means per group only
df[, mean(E),by=.(F)]
```

Comment: Thanks!!! But the code doesnt seem to satisfy the conditions mentioned in the reference post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `dt<-data.table(df)
dt[,Avg:=mean(E),by="F"]
dt <- unique(dt,by="F")`

this is the result:

```
 `E  F      Avg
1: 3.130658 -1 3.653132
2: 4.949555  0 2.797826
```

Doing only this : `dt<-data.table(df)
dt[,Avg:=mean(E),by="F"]`

You get: `E  F      Avg
 1: 3.130658 -1 3.653132
 2: 4.175605 -1 3.653132
 3: 4.949555  0 2.797826
 4: 4.653496  0 2.797826
 5: 4.382673  0 2.797826
 6: 3.870951  0 2.797826
 7: 3.905366  0 2.797826
 8: 3.795199  0 2.797826
 9: 3.374741  0 2.797826
10: 3.104690  0 2.797826
11: 2.801179  0 2.797826
12: 2.487881  0 2.797826
13: 2.449350  0 2.797826
14: 2.405410  0 2.797826
15: 2.090902  0 2.797826
16: 1.632416  0 2.797826
17: 1.700584  0 2.797826
18: 1.846504  0 2.797826
19: 1.949798  0 2.797826
20: 1.963114  0 2.797826
21: 2.033100  0 2.797826
22: 2.014313  0 2.797826
23: 1.997178  0 2.797826
24: 2.143775  0 2.797826`

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but the code doesnt seem to satisfy the conditions that are mentioned in the reference post.

Comment: Try the second solution @ANmike

Comment: No No, `row 2` is the last point where there is `-1` in column `F`, so average should be calculated  from `row 3` till `row 7` of `column B`, and `Avg` column should be `0` after from `row 8`

Comment: @ANmike Then i didn't understand what you want. Can you explain explicitly ?